# How to convert large amount of List<object> data into JSONobject?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

So I have to convert `List<ClassObject>` rows into JsonObjects to send into rest call. List has around 10,000 rows data. so can anyone please suggest me a easy way to convert List data in JsonObject? for now i am iterating the list data using for loop and then putting into JsonObject but it is taking so much time.

```
for (DeviceMasterForm dirtyForm : dirtyMasterFormsOnly) {

            tableObject = new JSONObject();
            tableObject.put("id", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getId());
            tableObject.put("strFormTitle", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getStrFormTitle());
            tableObject.put("iTemplateVersionNumber", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getiTemplateVersionNumber());
            tableObject.put("iViewSequence", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getiViewSequence());
            tableObject.put("hasConditions", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getHasConditions());
            tableObject.put("flgDeleted", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getFlgDeleted());
            tableObject.put("dtCreated", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getDtCreated());
            tableObject.put("dtUpdated", dirtyForm.getMasterForm().getDtUpdated());

            tableJsonArray.put(tableObject);
        }

Exected result = [{"key":"value","key":"value"},{"key":"value","key":"value"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has an in-build json serializer. You can do something like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<MyObject> getList() {
        //return your List Object here, Spring Boot will serialize it
        return new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my answer now you can see what type of result i want in json form

Comment: Spring Boot uses https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson for serialization. That means: your object in the list has to be a POJO with Getters and the Result should be like you expect it.